# How to move drop down left in blackberry + java

Tags: blackberry

I am using `ObjectChoiceField` example. it is showing drop down at the end of right side, but i need to show some margin on the left side .

how we can achieve this ?

```java
String choices[] = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
        int iSetTo = 0;
        VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager(){
            protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                graphics.clear();
                super.paint(graphics);
            }
        };
        vfm.add(new ObjectChoiceField("Day of the week",choices,iSetTo){
            protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                super.paint(graphics);
            }
        });
```

I am using this example:

![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with many fields by setting their **margin**.  [Field#setMargin()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setMargin%28net.rim.device.api.ui.XYEdges%29) has been available since BBOS 6.0 officially, but was undocumented and usable in 5.0 (at least), too.  So, at this point, I consider it perfectly acceptable to use in 5.0+ apps.

For example:

```java
   public ChoiceMarginScreen() {
      super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

      String choices[] = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
      int iSetTo = 0;
      VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(); 
      vfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLACK));

      ObjectChoiceField days = new ObjectChoiceField("Day of the week", choices, iSetTo) {
         protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            super.paint(graphics);
         }
      };
      // set margin XYEdges(top, right, bottom, left):
      days.setMargin(new XYEdges(0, 150, 0, 0));

      vfm.add(days);
      add(vfm);
   }
```

Note that you also don't need to override the `VerticalFieldManager#paint()` method just to set a solid background color.  You can use `setBackground()` for that.  For setting the white font color on your object choice field, though, overriding `paint()` is a fine solution.

*Also: I just went off your screen shot, and assumed you wanted the choice field moved to the left, but with no other field to the right of it.  If you want the choice field to the left to make room for another field on its right, then you probably want to put both those fields in a `HorizontalFieldManager`, representing a row, and then add that `HorizontalFieldManager` to your `VerticalFieldManager`.  But, that's not what you showed, so I offer my answer above.*

Comment: Note: OP removed screenshot after accepting, but despite the original language, the screenshot clearly showed that margin on the **right** side, not the left, was wanted.  That's why my example above sets a right margin, not a left margin.